# Invalid Podfile file: "react-native-community/cli" type of error

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, podfile

I am failing to install iOS dependencies using `pod install` annd after pressing enter button to run `pod install`.

**Node Version:** v16.16.0

**NPM Version:** 8.11.0

> Working Process which I followed:

1. **First way to install pod:** Firstly install npm then install pod
2. **Second way to install pod:** after deleting ***node_modules*** then run `pod install`

Failed to install to follow the both of rules as mentioned before and to check the error, please check the attached file.

> The dependencies are install in our projects as given below as ***package.json*** file.

```
{
  "name": "shohan",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.16.2",
    "@react-native-community/blur": "^3.6.0",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios": "^8.0.6",
    "@react-native-community/clipboard": "^1.5.1",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^6.1.2",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.6",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.4.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.2.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.5.0",
    "@rneui/base": "^0.0.0-edge.2",
    "@rneui/themed": "^0.0.0-edge.2",
    "@twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input": "^1.3.11",
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.2",
    "radio-buttons-react-native": "^1.0.4",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.28.1",
    "react-native": "0.67.3",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-audio-record": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-bar-chart": "^0.1.0",
    "react-native-countdown-component": "^2.7.1",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^4.2.0",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.3.0",
    "react-native-elevation": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-emoji-selector": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.8.4",
    "react-native-infinite-scrolling": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-pager-view": "^5.4.15",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.12.1",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.4",
    "react-native-pure-chart": "^0.0.24",
    "react-native-render-html": "^6.3.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.1.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.13.1",
    "react-native-skeleton-placeholder": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.11.2",
    "react-native-step-indicator": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-super-grid": "^4.4.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.4.0",
    "react-native-swiper-flatlist": "^3.0.16",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-text-gradient": "^0.1.7",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.1.0",
    "react-native-video": "^2.3.1",
    "react-native-video-player": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.18.1",
    "react-native-youtube-iframe": "^2.2.2",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.17.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^27.5.1",
    "eslint": "^8.11.0",
    "jest": "^27.5.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.69.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

> Here is the **Podfile's** code is given below,

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'shohan' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => false
  )

  target 'shohanTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  use_flipper!()

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
```

The occurred error is given in the attached file please check it and help me.

[image: Podfile type of error]